# Cut a matrix at regular intervals

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of 360 columns and 20 lines, I wish to be able to cut this matrix into 18 regular matrices <20 * 20> i.e. 20 columns and 20 rows
I am trying to use `mat2cell` i have an error message. do you have an idea

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: @ Pri  Error in syntax dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mat2cell` you must provide the dimensions of *each element* so we need to create an array of 20's that has the same number of entries as the number of columns divided by 20 as the third input.

```
mat2cell(data, 20,  repmat(20, 1, size(data, 2) / 20))
```

Alternately, you could do some reshaping followed by a call to `num2cell` which in my opinion is much easier to work with

```
squeeze(num2cell(permute(reshape(data, [], 20, 20), [2 3 1]),[1 2]))
```

Comment: I have an error message when i use                                               mat2cell(matrice, repmat(20, 1, size(matrice, 1) / 20), 20) also  the second syntax

Comment: for syntax (1)                                                                                                         Attempt to execute SCRIPT mat2cell as a function:
C:\Users\Tarhouni\Documents\MATLAB\mat2cell.m--------------->
Error in mast_wonted (line 45) --------------------------------->                                              new_Matrices= mat2cell(Matrice, repmat(20, 1, size(Matrice, 1) / 20), 20);

Comment: You have a file named `mat2cell` on your path (C:\Users\Tarhouni\Documents\MATLAB\mat2cell.m) that is getting in the way of the *real* `mat2cell` function

Comment: Error using mat2cell (line 107)
Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [20  360].'

Error in mast_wonted (line 45)--->
new_Matrices= mat2cell(Matrice, repmat(20, 1, size(Matrice, 1) / 20), 20);

Comment: @liomar I just realized your data is `20 x 360` rather than `360 x 20`. Updated.

Comment: I have a matrix of  20 lines and 360 columns

Comment: @liomar Are you sure you're using the latest version above? I modified it a little while ago to add a missing `)`

Comment: @ Suever Thank you for your help. It works with the two syntax